# How can I show that $X\setminus Y$ is dense in $X$ if $X$ is a normed space?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, dense-subspaces

> Let $X$ be a normed space and $Y$ a subspace s.t. $Y\neq X$. I need to show that $X\setminus Y$ is dense in $X$.

I'm a bit confused how to do this. I thought about this geometrically, so I thought that it is enough to show that for all open balls $B(x_0,r_0)$ with $x_0\in X$, $r_0>0$ there exists $x\in (X\setminus Y)\cap B(x_0,r_0)$.
But now somehow I don't see how to construct such an $x$. I thought then about proving the statement by contradiction but also this does not brings me further. Could maybe someone help me?

My approach was to assume $(X\setminus Y)\cap B(x_0,r_0)=\emptyset$, this would imply that $B(x_0,r_0)\subset Y$. But then in particular $x_0\in Y$. Now I thought that since $x_0$ is arbitrary in $X$ this would mean that $X\subset Y$ but then in particular $X=Y$ which gives a contradiction.

But I don't think this is true.

Comment: There must be some element $x$ which is in $X$ but not in $Y$. What can you say about $x/n + y$, where $y \in Y$ and $n$ is any natural number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a \in X \setminus Y$. For any $x \in X$, the sequence $\{x+\frac{a}{n}\}$ converges to $x$ and belongs to $X \setminus Y$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but wouldn't my prove work and if not why? It would be very helpful to me if you could explain me why my proof fails.

Comment: The problem with your proof is that you would only prove that **it exists at least one** $x_0$ having the given property. Which is not enough to conclude that $X=Y$. To convince yourself about that, write precisely the negation of a subset being not dense.

Comment: ah but could one fix this or is it not so easy

Comment: Not easy as I think that the negation you used for a subset not being dense is not correct.

Comment: ah okey I see. So I need to use your sequence and then I'm immediately done by definition, right?

Comment: There s is a minor error; If $x=-a$ then $x +\frac  a n \in Y$ for $n=1$.  What is  true is $x +\frac  a n \in Y$ for at most one value of $n$.

Comment: It suffices to approximate elements of $Y.$ For $y\in Y$ and any $x\notin Y$ the sequence $y+(x/n)$ tends to $y.$

Answer (score 1):

Your logic doesn't quite work. You've taken an arbitrary $x_0$. But then you impose the restriction that $B(x_0,r_0)$ is entirely contained in $Y$. This restricts the possible values $x_0$ can take.

This does not mean you have reached a contradiction. It just means that instead of picking an arbitrary $x_0\in X$, you have now picked an arbitrary $x_0$ among all the elements in $X$ such that $B(x_0,r_0)\subseteq Y$.